# Outputting plain text with <br /> tags in JSX

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to output the following HTML structure using React JS and JSX. I don't want to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as this data is settable by our users.

Any of the lines could be missing as no piece of data is required and there should be no blank lines left such as would be if the data

```
<p>
  one<br />
  two<br />
  three<br />
  four
</p>
```

I currently have this:

```
<p className='address__details'>
  { this.line_1.length > 0 ? `${this.line_1}<br />` : `` }
  { this.line_2.length > 0 ? `${this.line_2}<br />` : `` }
  { this.line_3.length > 0 ? `${this.line_3}<br />` : `` }
  { this.line_4.length > 0 ? `${this.line_4}<br />` : `` }
</p>
```

As I understand tertiary conditions are required no `if` work inside of a JSX return statement. This just outputs text on the page, the `<br />` tags are not interpreted as HTML.

Is it possible to output this as in my example or am I going to have to do away with the `<br />` tags and use `<div>`s for the newlines?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my function, works only for BR tags

```
function textToHtml(html)
{
    let arr = html.split(/<br\s*\/?>/i);
    return arr.reduce((el, a) => el.concat(a, <br />), []);
}
```

How to use:

```
<p>{textToHtml(this.state.text)}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any HTML markup inside strings will be escaped, so you're going to have to properly wrap the lines with a container element:

```
{ this.line_1.length > 0 ? <p>{ this.line_1 }</p> : null }
```

Comment: so I basically can't get away from wrapping each line in an element?

Comment: @ToniLeigh I don't think so, unless you're willing to consider a CSS solution, like [`white-space: pre-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values)

Answer (score 0):

While not particularly elegant, you could do this

```
{ this.line_1.length > 0 ? `${this.line_1}` : `` }{ this.line_1.length > 0 ? <br /> : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more or less elegantly by using for-loop and `push`-ing text line and `<br/>` separately:

```
const textLines = [ "one", "two", "three", "four" ]
const lines = []
for (var item of textLines) {
  lines.push(item)
  lines.push(<br/>)
}
return (<p>{lines}</p>)
```